# Linux distro in Windows LAN

Tags: linux-distributions

For a destop PC to be used in a Windows network, e.g. DHCP/DNS server runing Windows Server 2012 and SQL Server running the same OS, all other clients runing xp, which would be the most convinient Linux distro choice?

p.s.: Since, most of the Linux distro's are not commercial os', this should not be considered an off topic question i think.

Comment: Honestly, based on the assumption that only things that matter are DHCP/DNS and SQL Server which is running on Windows server... It does not matter - I mean it is up to you which distro to use. Any Linux distro will be able to utilize DHCP/DNS and SQL provided by Windows server. So pick one which is more convenient for end user.

Comment: Not sure why you think that because Linux is "not commercial" (which several Linux flavors actually are) that it makes it OK for you to ask us to recommend a product.  Product recommendations are off-topic, regardless of cost or licensing of said product.  Pick one you like, and try/use it. If you run into actual problems while attempting to use the one you chose, come back with those.

Comment: What's the best cheese to put on a ham and cheese sandwich?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, based on the assumption that only things that matter in this question are DHCP/DNS and SQL Server which is running on Windows server - it does not matter (from technical viewpoint) which distro to use. Any modern Linux distro will be able to utilize DHCP/DNS and SQL provided by Windows server.

So this choice should be based not on technical side of things, but on user preference / convenience. Use [Linux Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/) or [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/) for experienced user and for example [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) for new user.

Comment: Correct.  Basic network services are no issue here.